# Google Script to define variables in If statement in a loop

Tags: for-loop, if-statement, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm new to Google Script. And I'd like to create a function that checks if the content has been filled up correctly. If some columns don't contain the specific words or they contain nothing while the value of column L is "Y", then it should show an alert message accordingly. If everything is good, then show the message "Campaign info's been added correctly!"

Here's the script that I wrote:

```
function Validation() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getMaxRows(), sheet.getMaxColumns());

  for (var i = 0; i < range.length; i++) {
    var campaign_live = range.getCell(i, 12).getValue();
    var test_type = range.getCell(i, 6).getValue();
    if (campaign_live == "Y" && test_type != "Subject" && test_type!= "Sender") {
      Browser.msgBox("Wrong Test Type in Column G, please check.", Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL);
    } 
    var Template = range.getCell(i, 8).getValue();
    if (campaign_live == "Y" && Template != "HTML" && Template!= "TEXT") {
      Browser.msgBox("Wrong Template in Column H, please check.", Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL);
    } 
    var Sender = range.getCell(i, 9).getValue();
    if (campaign_live == "Y" && Sender == "" ) {
      Browser.msgBox("Missing Sender in Column I, please check.", Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL);
    }
    var Subject = range.getCell(i, 10).getValue();
    if (campaign_live == "Y" && Subject == "" ) {
      Browser.msgBox("Missing Subject in Column J, please check.", Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL);
    }
    var Content = range.getCell(i, 11).getValue();
    if (campaign_live == "Y" && Content == "" ) {
      Browser.msgBox("Missing Content in Column K, please check.", Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL);
    }  
  }
  Browser.msgBox("Campaign info's been added correctly!");
}
```

The script can be executed, however, no matter what content I have in the cells that I have indicated in the loop, it only shows the message "Campaign info's been added correctly!". It seems to me the loop part is totally ignored in the process.

Do you have any idea why it doesn't work?
Thanks a lot in advance for your kind response.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues. The biggest is that you can't use `range.length`. `range` is an Object, not an Array. Instead, use `range.getHeight()`.

```
function Validation() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getMaxRows(), sheet.getMaxColumns());

  var ok = true;
  for (var i = 1;i <= range.getHeight(); i++) {
    var campaign_live = range.getCell(i, 12).getValue();
    var test_type = range.getCell(i, 7).getValue();
    if (campaign_live == "Y" && test_type != "Subject" && test_type!= "Sender"){
      ok = false;
      Browser.msgBox("Wrong Test Type in Column G, please check.", Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL);
    } 
    var Template = range.getCell(i, 8).getValue();
    if (campaign_live == "Y" && Template != "HTML" && Template!= "TEXT"){
      ok = false;
      Browser.msgBox("Wrong Template in Column H, please check.", Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL);
    } 
    var Sender = range.getCell(i, 9).getValue();
    if (campaign_live == "Y" && Sender == "" ) {
      ok = false;
      Browser.msgBox("Missing Sender in Column I, please check.", Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL);
    } 
    var Subject = range.getCell(i, 10).getValue();
    if (campaign_live == "Y" && Subject == "" ) {
      ok = false;
      Browser.msgBox("Missing Subject in Column J, please check.", Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL);
    } 
    var Content = range.getCell(i, 11).getValue();
    if (campaign_live == "Y" && Content == "" ) {
      ok = false;
      Browser.msgBox("Missing Content in Column K, please check.", Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL);
    }  
  }
  if (ok) {
    Browser.msgBox("Campaign info's been added correctly!");
  }
}
```

I made three other modifications:

1. Added an `ok` boolean. This will prevent the "Campaign info's been added correctly!" if an error message ever appears.
2. In `test_type`, you were selecting `getCell(1, 6)`, but that's column F, not G.
3. `i` now starts at 1, because the ranges are 1-indexed. (Arrays are 0-indexed.)

Comment: You should change `getMax___()` to `getLast____()`, to avoid senseless iteration beyond the realm of entered data. You should also promote import of the range as an actual Javascript array, rather than repeated use of the Spreadsheet interface, since this will result in an absolutely massive reduction in execution time required.

Comment: Yes, and you're correct that working with the array of values would be more efficient, but I was struggling to limit myself to simply answering the question rather than reworking the entire solution. I would also suggest identifying the particular cell that raised an error, potentially changing its bg-color, and using only the "OK" button as "CANCEL" currently has the same functionality.

Answer (score 0):

The for-loop is not entered, as the loop criteria does not evaluate as true, for the reason that the `Range` class has no `length` property (which results in the comparison `0 < undefined`).

Additionally, there are other issues with your code that can be improved

1. You use the Spreadsheet interface repeatedly - this is very slow if compared to reading the data into memory, and then operating on it directly.
2. Your iteration bounds are excessive, because you reference `getMax___()` as opposed to `getLast___()`. The 'last' versions consider only rows with data, vs. any possible row in the sheet, even if completely devoid of data.
3. You re-test the same quantity - `campaign_live` - repeatedly for the same row.
4. You prompt the user repeatedly, each of which requires immediate reaction. One improvement is to only prompt at the end of validation. An even better approach (left to the reader) is to categorize which rows have which problems, and report the associated message once, along with all offending rows.

An improved script:

```
function Validation() {
  // Rather than immediately prompt about bad/missing data, prompt only at the end.
  var msgs = [];

  // Read all the "occupied" ranges' values into a Javascript "2D" array.
  var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getValues();
  // Remove the header row from the data.
  var headers = values.splice(0, 1);

  // Iterate this array (as opposed to re-querying the Spreadsheet multiple times).
  // Arrays are 0-based, so cell(1, 12) is array index [0][11].
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    // If this campaign is not live, there is no reason to validate it.
    var campaign_live = values[i][11];
    if (campaign_live !== "Y") {
      continue;
    }

    var test_type = values[i][6];
    if (test_type !== "Subject" && test_type !== "Sender") {
      msgs.push("Wrong Test Type in Column G, please check.");
    }
    var Template = values[i][7];
    if (Template !== "HTML" && Template !== "TEXT") {
      msgs.push("Wrong Template in Column H, please check.");
    }
    var Sender = values[i][8];
    if (Sender == "" ) {
      msgs.push("Missing Sender in Column I, please check.");
    }
    var Subject = values[i][9];
    if (Subject == "" ) {
      msgs.push("Missing Subject in Column J, please check.");
    }
    var Content = values[i][10];
    if (Content == "" ) {
      msgs.push("Missing Content in Column K, please check.");
    }
  }

  // Report any messages that were added.
  var message = (msgs.length > 0) ? msgs.join("\n") : "Campaign info's been added correctly!";
  Browser.msgBox(message);
}
```

Comment: It works perfectly! Thank you! I have taken your advice to add the color in the cells with mistake also.